# Wider space between minus sign and number when surrounded by verts

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols

When I write the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\begin{document}  

$$
-1, -2, -3, \dots \| -1 \|, \| -2 \|, \| -3 \|
$$

\end{document}
```

It produces the following:
[image: Problem]

As you can see, the negative signs are more closely coupled with the constants in the first three numbers, but this fails to be the case when surrounded by norm signs, which I find aesthetically displeasing.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `\|` on the wild. `\|` on the wild is an *ord* atom, you need to ensure that the first `\|` gets *open* atom, and the last one *close* atom. Use `\lVert` and `\rVert`, or `\bigl\|` and `\bigr\|` (or any other size, `\Big(l|r)`, `\bigg(l|r)`, `\Bigg(l|r)`); or use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` (from `mathtools`) to define `\norm{-1}` or `\norm[\Big]{-2}` to get different sizes.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. However, this problem doesn't arise when using `(` and `)`, that is to say, I don't need to use `\left(` and `\right)` to avoid this issue. I'm curious why I have to use `\lVert` and `\rVert` here.

Comment: the parentheses are defined at the outset to be *open* and *close* atoms, as are other "naturally" paired delimiters.  the vert bars have no "natural" orientation, so that must be indicated specifically when they are used as delimiters.

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered, the symbols generated by `\vert` (equivalently: `|`) and `\Vert` (equivalently: `\|`) have status "math-ordinary". Hence, TeX interprets the `-` symbol as a *binary operator*, since the `-` symbol is sandwiched between two symbols (`\Vert` and a numeral) with status "math-ordinary". (This is, of course, the correct default behavior for expressions such as `$a-b$`.) To get TeX to treat the `-` symbol as a *unary operator*, it's advisable to use `\lVert` and `\rVert`, which have status "math-open" and "math-close", respectively, instead of just `\Vert`.

Better still, define a LaTeX macro called, say, `\norm`, which automatically uses the correct math status values for the opening and closing fences. In the code below, the macro `\norm` is set up in such a way that `\norm*` is defined as well; the latter lets the size of the "fences" grow automatically, as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}  

Original form:

$
-1, -2, -3, \dots, \| -1 \|, \| -2 \|, \| -3 \|
$

\medskip
Better:

$
-1, -2, -3, \dots, \lVert -1 \rVert, \lVert -2 \rVert, \lVert -3 \rVert
$

\medskip
Best:

$
-1, -2, -3, \dots, \norm{-1}, \norm{-2}, \norm{-3}
$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The minus sign sees the left delimiter as the first argument of a subtraction operation and sets the space as such.  Enclosing the `-` in braces forces it to treat the minus as a unary operator (a negation on the following number). (Likewise, I could enclose the whole number in braces as `\| {-1} \|`)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}  

\[
  -1, -2, -3, \dots \| {-}1 \|, \| {-}2 \|, \| {-}3 \|
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]